# Classification of restricted Lie algebras of reductive groups

Tags: lie-algebras, reductive-groups, characteristic-p, modular-representation-theory, restricted-lie-algebras

$\DeclareMathOperator\Lie{Lie}$Let $G/K$ be a reductive group over a field $K$. In characteristic $0$ the Lie algebra is invariant under base change of fields, so to understand $\Lie(G)$ it is enough to understand $\Lie(G_{\overline{K}})$. Both semisimple Lie algebras and reductive groups over $\overline{K}$ are classified by root systems and Dynkin diagrams. So in this case $\Lie(G)$ roughly contains the information of the isomorphism (isogeny?) class of $G_{\overline{K}}$.

If $K=\mathbb{F}_q$ is a finite field we can consider $\Lie(G)$ as a restricted Lie algebra. Does the restricted Lie algebra contains more information about $G$ than its Lie algebra? E.g. do they exist $G,G'$ having isomorphic Lie algebras, but not restricted Lie algebras? I could also ask the question replacing the restricted Lie algebra by the universal enveloping algebra $U\mathfrak{g}$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ (without divided powers).

Comment: If $K / \mathbb F_q$ is a quadratic extension, I get $\mathrm{Lie}(U(2)) = \{ A : K^2 \to K^2 \mid A^T = - A^F\}$, which base changes over $K$ to $\mathrm{Lie}(GL_2)$ using isomorphism $K \otimes_{\mathbb F_q} K \cong K \oplus K$.

Comment: @JoshuaMundinger Right, that makes sense. I have changed that part.